# Order filled above limit buy price?

Tags: limit-order

I’m learning still and new to trading. Bought USO buy limit 13.22. It was filled at 13.38?  Is there an additional fee added to ETFs? What am I missing?

---

I called. They add the commission into the price per share to reflect total cost.

Comment: Additional fees would not be reflected in the price, but as a separate "transaction cost". Have you contacted your broker or provider to see what they say? Are you sure it wasn't a "stop" order?

Comment: Is your broker Fidelity by chance? They add commission to the cost basis, which is displayed as "cost" in some places.

Comment: That's a disadvantage of most ETFs, there is a spread between buying and selling price - but therefore you can trade them immediately. If you buy your broker's index funds, they are mostly free of that, but they trade once a day only.

Answer (score 8):

If you placed a limit order to buy USO at $13.22 and your fill price was $13.38 then:

- You placed the order incorrectly (a market order?)
- You're looking at the cost basis which includes the commission
- Your broker screwed up

Call your broker for clarification.